# Cassandra and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and Hadoop. I am trying to read cassandra data on hourly basis and dump into HDFS. Cassandra and Hadoop are on different clusters. Any pointers on Clients/API I could use to do this is much appreciated.

Comment: You should specify the Programming Language

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Java because Hadoop and Cassandra are both Java based.  Astyanax is a good Java Cassandra API.

I've used org.apache.hadoop to write to HDFS using Java but there might be something better out there.